# What are all the atomic operations in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu-atomics

I was wondering if there is a complete list of atomic operations usable in CUDA kernels. I couldn't find something like that on the internet.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

See the CUDA Programming Guide [section on atomic functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions).

Answer (score 9):

As of April 2020 (i.e. CUDA 10.2, Turing michroarchitecture), these are:

- addition
- subtraction
- minimum
- maximum
- bitwise-and
- bitwise-or
- bitwise-xor
- increment (with a wraparound value)
- decrement (with a wraparound value)
- compare-and-swap - which is perhaps the most significant, as you can "implement" essentially any atomic operation using compare-and-swap.

Note, however, that:

- Only certain data types are directly supported (of size never above 8 bytes).
- Earlier micro-architectures support less operations and/or less types.
- CUDA memory only supports *aligned* accesses - whether they be regular or atomic.

For details, consult the [Atomic Functions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) section of the [CUDA Programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/).